# iOS: IBAction not called during animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

In my app I call this method to move a UIButton

```
- (void) buttonMovement{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         // do whatever animation you want, e.g.,
                         play_bt.center = CGPointMake(play_bt.center.x, play_bt.center.y-20);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
}
```

In this way my button done an "up&down" movement but if I "push" it, IBAction doesn't work. If I don't do this animation it work fine. Why?
If this animation is a problem to call the action, what's the way to do an animation that don't give me problems?
Another way is to move the button as an imageview and over I put an invisible button, but I lost the press effetcts, and it became all noise.

Comment: The title of the thread is "IBAction not called during animation", however you have pasted a void method?

Comment: I wrote that it is my animation method, it's not util show the IBAction, it's not called...

Comment: @nazz_areno I think this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446966/clicking-an-animating-image-button. Use touches began instead of IBAction.

Comment: Your post is not at all clear. Where is the IBAction method? (The code you posted is a void method, not an IBAction.) Are you saying that you can't click the button while it is "in flight" during an animation? Or are you saying that you can't click on it once the animation has completed?

Comment: You cannot click on buttons while they are moving across the screen. It is possible to detect taps on objects that are being animated, but it requires special code that checks on the presentation layer of the object being animated, and the CALayer hitTest method. Button IBActions will never work on an "in-flight" animation of an object's center until the animation is complete.

Comment: Isn't this what the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` option is used for?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, that flag will allow user interaction, but doesn't solve the problem that a view object that is animating across the screen will actually only accept taps at the end location of it's animation while the animation is in-flight. In order to get taps to work on an in-flight animation you have to both set the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction flag AND use a hitTest on the object's layer.presentationLayer.

Comment: ...and the button will not trigger its action from an in-between position during an animation that causes it to move.

Comment: @DuncanC I though so but wasn't sure. I don't use UIView animations that often.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, UIView animations are really just syntactic sugar that creates one or more CAAnimations for you, and also set the ending value of the property being animated to it's final value. So they have the same limitations as CAAnimations.

Comment: Probably Adding `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` to animation options

Comment: @Srikanth. No. That will not work. That will let you click the button at it's view coordinates, which start at the view's initial location, and then at the movement the animation starts, the button's view coordinates snap to the end position. Buttons will not respond to clicks at their "in-flight" animation position.

Comment: To all those complaining "his question doesn't make sense", "he said `IBAction` method in his title, yet posted a `void` method": `IBAction` is simply a `#define` for `void` (see `UINibDeclarations.h` for more info). So the method he posted could very well be an `IBAction` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to implement touchesBegan instead of IBAction for your animating button.

You may want to check the answers given here:[Clicking an animating image / button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446966/clicking-an-animating-image-button)

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{

    // Get location of touched point
    CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    //
    // Check if point is inside your button frame
    // or compare it with the presentation layer
    //

}
```

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people are providing wrong information here. I tried to weigh in with comments. Now it's time to post a conclusive answer. To quote my answer to the "[**clicking an animating image/button**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446966/clicking-an-animating-image-button)" question linked by @Radu above:

The short answer is that you can't tap views while they are animating. The reason is that the views don't actually travel from the start to the end location. Instead, the system uses a "presentation layer" in Core Animation to create the appearance of your view object moving/rotating/scaling/whatever.

What you have to do is attach a tap gesture recognizer to a containing view that completely encloses the animation (maybe the entire screen) and then write code that looks at the coordinates of the tap, does coordinate conversion, and decides if the tap is on a view that you care about. If the tap is on a button and you want the button to highlight you'll need to handle that logic too.

I have a sample project on github that shows how to do this when you are doing both UIView animation and Core Animation with CABasicAnimation (which animates layers, not views.)

[**Core Animation demo with hit testing**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo)

Comment: yeah finally @Radu link solved my problem, thank you too for the examples